# Get Cordova app to show up on iOS "Share To" menu

Tags: ios, cordova, socialshare

Here is my scenario:

I am writing an application which allows users to play games and share their scores on a public "scoreboard" platform. So basically, you play a game like Temple Run, then when you die, you would hit the "Share with my friends button".

[image: Share to menu image]

It should look something like the image above. I want the user to be able to see the icon of my Cordova application here.

How can I get my application to show up in that menu, and get the contents of the message (Which should be something like: "Try beating me in temple run 2 with a score of 60")